# Cannot find name error ionic2 angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Very new to ionic/angular/typescript. I am trying to fetch json from a local rails server. The error I keep getting is "Cannot find name 'MessageService'" when serving up ionic/cordova. My message-service.ts file looks like so

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getMessages() {
    let messages = this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/conversations/1/messages`);
    return messages;
  }
}
```

This may be a hint, sublime highlights MessageService and mentions "experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release."

My code for home.ts is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../../services/message-service';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ MessageService ]
})
export class HomePage {

  public foundMessages;

  constructor(private message: MessageService) {

  }

  getMessages() {
    this.message.getMessages().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.foundMessages = data.json();
        },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('get Messages completed')
        )
  }

}
```

very new to this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: restart `ionic serve`?

Comment: @hgoebl restarting it is not working :/